# Stringify occurring before value of variables get placed

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, firebase, stringify

I build a dictionary with a few variables.

I stringify it and send it as a PUT request.

The request goes through, however the fields all end up being populated with the name of the variables (`friendRequest`, `friendRequester`, `requestedFriend`) instead of their values !

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createChatRoom", function(request, response) {

  var friendRequest = request.params.friendRequestId.toString();
  var friendRequester = request.params.friendRequester.toString();
  var requestedFriend = request.params.requestedFriend.toString();

  var chatPayload = {}
  chatPayload["room"] = {friendRequest: true};
  chatPayload["members"] = {friendRequest: {friendRequester: true, requestedFriend: true}}

  (...)

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://myapp.firebaseIO.com/app' + '.json',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {'auth': token},
    body: JSON.stringify(chatPayload)
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
      response.success("Successfully created chat room!");
  },function(httpResponse) {
      response.error("failed to create chat room" + httpResponse.text)
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried passing Content-Type as 'application/json' in your params property? The http request client you are using may default to something other than that.

Comment: First of all, you should use the dot syntax for `chatPayload.room` and `chatPayload.members`. Secondly, you should be using `x.toString()` rather than `String( x )` to cast to string explicitly.

Comment: @PitaJ gotcha, any ideas on the issue ?

Comment: @CaptainAdams any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try separation of concerns here and first construct your object with a function and launch the Ajax call with a callback once your object is created?

Comment: @DaveGomez Please check out my answer and if you find a more concise way of writing it, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question:

It seems like it was `stringify`ing even the variable names because as keys, they weren't being declared.

Declaring every key individually using an indexer worked for me, however it appears unnecessarily verbose. There must be a more concise way...

```
  var chatPayload = {};
  chatPayload.room = {};
  chatPayload.room[friendRequest] = true;

  chatPayload.members = {};
  chatPayload.members[friendRequest] = {};
  chatPayload.members[friendRequest][friendRequester] = true
  chatPayload.members[friendRequest][requestedFriend] = true
```